# Quantitative determination of chemical composition of a simple unknown mixture

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, concentration

> - Unknown mixture A [$\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{CuSO4}$]
> - Unknown mixture B [$\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{HNO3}$] (ranged between $\pu{0.1 - 0.3 M}$ for the solution)
>
> (E.g. if you are using Unknown mixture B [$\ce{H2SO4}$ and $\ce{HNO3}$], concentration of $\ce{H2SO4}$ will be $\pu{0.1 – 0.3 mol/dm3}$, and concentration of $\ce{HNO3}$ will be $\pu{0.1 – 0.3 mol/dm3}$.)
>
> - Sodium hydroxide [$\ce{NaOH}$] solution (approximately 2.0 M 1.0M)
> - Potassium hydrogen phthalate [$\ce{C8H5KO4}$] powder
> - Barium chloride [$\ce{BaCl2}$] solution ($\pu{0.3 M}$)
> - Copper sulfate pentahydrate [$\ce{CuSO4.5H2O}$] powder
>
> You may choose to use spectrophotometric, titrimetric, or gravimetric methods to execute your analysis. There are no major restrictions apart from non-wasteful use of chemical reagents.

How do I approach this?

I tend to use the gravimetric method to perform crystallization of anhydrous copper sulfate so I can measure the mass of $\ce{CuSO4}$ in Mixture A, but for this experiment I will need $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$, which not provided.

Using spectrophotometry, I will be able to find the concentration of $\ce{CuSO4}$ in the mixture as copper sulfate pentahydrate ($\ce{CuSO4.5H2O}$) powder is given, and I can make a blank out of the chemical is it true?

Comment: Homework questions must demonstrate some effort to understand the underlying concepts. For help asking a good homework question, see: [How do I ask homework questions on Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange)?